# Full UV wrapping on a mirrored Mesh

Tags: texturing, uv, mirror

I have an object with a mirror modifier in X and Y direction. Is it possible to unwrap all the 4 quadrants as a big single UV map and then have this UV map to apply to the object as it was a single non mirrored object (Same as apply in the mirror modifier), without using the Apply button first?

I wan't to be able to edit the mesh with the Mirror modifier later on, but have the UV map seeing it as one single object.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, this **is possible** (out of the box).  The mirror modifier has a mirror UV option, so you can mirror either the U or V (or both) texture coordinates.  So for example, you can model the left hand side of a head with the mirror modifier enabled for X and U.  Then unwrap it to the left-hand side of your texture.  The mirrored right-hand side of the mesh will have its UV co-ordinates on the right-hand side of the texture, so you can have something different there, e.g. a scar drawn on the texture's right cheek which appears on the right cheek of the mirrored model.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - even though this does not allow mapping freely the vertices of only one side, it allows exactly what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is **not possible** (out of the box). You will have to apply the modifier if you want a unique texture on each part of your mesh.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use the UV Project modifier.

You need to add 3 empty's, rotate one by 90 degrees in the X axis, and another one by 90 degrees in the Y axis. And thhen use these as UV Projectors; This works fine for a simple cube, but you might need something different for a more complex model.

[image]