# How do you avoid a UV Map from mirroring?

Tags: animation

So basically I keep trying to make both eyes look the same way in UV editing but every time I move the x-axis the model's left eye goes in the opposite direction. Is there anyway to avoid this?

Update: I actually added the pictures as well as the UV map I'm working with. I've tried unwrapping it and it seems that the UV map is the front and back of one single eye which is then also used for his other eye.

[image: The UB Editor]

[image: Before.]

[image: After.]

Comment: You can embed images directly in the post, just click the image icon when editing.

Comment: Select its UV and inverse with a SX-1?

Comment: Embedding the images is not only possible, but is highly recommended and aprreciated on this site.

Comment: I put the pictures in the post itself.
Also SX-1 did not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18506/full-uv-wrapping-on-a-mirrored-mesh

Comment: Please share your file (only keep the useful objects)